# Leer archivo .txt

Tags: javascript, java, python

Tengo este tipo de archivo .txt:

```
"u901_humext    ""2019-02-10 00:00""    99.89   100.2   99.98568627451"
"u901_humext    ""2019-02-10 00:01""    99.55   100     99.912962962963"
```

Donde `u901_humext` representa el nombre de un sensor, la fecha y hora que se han tomado los datos `99.89`,  `100.2`,  `99.9865`, ...
El archivo es muchos mas grande con más fechas y con más sensores.

En java lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera:

La clase `InformacionSensor` recoge los 4 ultimos datos (hora, min, max y avg).

```
public class InformacionSensor<T> implements Comparable<T> {

    private String hora;
    private double min;
    private double max;
    private double avg;

    public InformacionSensor(String hora, double min, double max,double avg) {
        this.hora = hora;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.avg = avg;
    }
}
```

La clase procesar datos es la siguiente:

```
public class ProcesarDatos {

    private TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, TreeSet<InformacionSensor>>> aux;

    public ProcesarDatos() {
        this.aux = new TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,TreeSet<InformacionSensor>>>();
    }

    public void cargarDatos(String archivo) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        String linea = "";
        String [] items = null;
        String nombre = "";

        String fecha = "";
        String hora= "";
        double min =.0;
        double max =.0;
        double avg = .0;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File(archivo));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()){
                linea = scan.nextLine();            
                items=linea.split("[\t \"]+");          
                nombre=items[1];
                fecha=items[2];
                hora=items[3];
                min=Double.parseDouble(items[4]);
                max=Double.parseDouble(items[5]);
                avg=Double.parseDouble(items[6]);

                InformacionSensor ifS = new InformacionSensor(hora, min, max, avg);

                TreeSet<InformacionSensor> t =new TreeSet<>();
                t.add(ifS);

                if(!this.aux.containsKey(nombre)) {
                    this.aux.put(nombre, new TreeMap<String, TreeSet<InformacionSensor>>());
                }if(!this.aux.get(nombre).containsKey(fecha)) {
                    this.aux.get(nombre).put(fecha, new TreeSet<InformacionSensor>());
                    this.aux.get(nombre).get(fecha).add(ifS);
                }
                this.aux.get(nombre).get(fecha).add(ifS);




            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

El `TreeMap` aux es o siguiente.

```
TreeMap<"NombreSensor", TreeMap<"Dia", TreeSet<InformacionSensor>>>
```

**La duda es:**

Necesito poner eso en una página web desde donde se pueda hacer consultas y que el resultado sea una gráfica del tipo: Introducir el nombre del sensor y el dia y que me aparezca las horas en el eje x y los "min" en el eje y

¿Que lenguaje utilizo? ¿Se puede pasar eso a JavaScript?

Gracias!

Comment: Por un lado, si lo tenes escrito en java, cual es el punto de migrar a otro lenguaje? Por otro lado.. tu pregunta está totalmente basada en opiniones (lo que no se admite en el sitio), te recomiendo que la reformules porque sino va a ser cerrada

Comment: La duda es que no se como utilizar eso para crear una pagina web...no migrar necesariamente a otro lenguaje.